# Stream with value changing from outside input

Tags: scala

I want to do

```
while(isRunning) {
   // do something
}
```

And be able from another thread to do `isRunning = false` and the above loop to stop.

However, I would like to do that in a more scala-like way.

One approach that I tried is :

```
object Watcher {
  var run: Boolean = true
  def getIsRunning: Stream[Boolean] = {
    { Thread.sleep(1000); run } #:: getIsRunning
  }
}
```

And then I was going to do:

```
Watcher.getIsRunning.takeWhile { isRunning => 
  if (isRunning) { 
     println("I am running")
  } else {
     println("I am not running")
  }
  isRunning
}
```

But it ( now obviously ) does not work because `takeWhile` return another stream and does not behave like a `while` loop which re-evaluate the value of `run` every time.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are referring to by "now obviously" ... it's not obvious to me why you think this should not work (in fact, I think, it should). I don't quite see why it needs to be so complicated (and what's wrong with a while loop), but functionally, there doesn't seem anything wrong with it ...

Another (arguably, even more "scala-like") way to do it, is using futures:

```
   def whileRunning(f: => Unit): Future[Unit] = Future(f).flatMap {
     case _ if isRunning => whileRunning(f)
     case _ => Future.successful
   }
```

Now, you can do `whileRunning(doWork)` ... and it's not blocking, so you can actually do `isRunning=true` some time later (make sure it's `@volatile`).

Comment: What does `@volatile` do?

Comment: @Wonay you should really, really avoid using mutable state in scala, until you familiarize yourself with [JVM memory model](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)

Comment: yes I know, I don't like mutable state either but I am not sure how to do it otherwise. I want an URL endpoint to be able to terminate the server

Comment: @Wonay `stop` the `ExecutionService`?

Comment: can you post an other answer explaining what you mean ?